# Views Auto-Refresh giving ajax error after some time

Tags: views

After creating views and implementing the views auto refresh on that it works fine for 8-10 minutes but after that giving error in alert "An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.Debugging information follows.Path: /?q=views/ajaxStatusText: errorResponseText:ReadyState: 0" and stop refreshing then. why it is happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: I tried in different browsers but it behaves same for all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me when views auto refresh ajax had not finished loading and I clicked on a link.

Here is a link to the drupal forum talking about this. https://www.drupal.org/node/1232416

I personally used the sandbox module in comment #183 to solve my problem.

Comment: thanks for reply but here I am using a table of user data with views auto refresh feature. so I just want to load and display any new data as it is added. no clicking is interfered on that page. It is just auto refreshing after each 5 seconds itself and after working fine for some time it suddenly pop up the ajax error. thanks.

Comment: hmmmm perhaps the original request didn't finish loading in 5 seconds and then gets another request, which would be the equivalent of clicking on a link and interrupting the ajax before it finishes.

Comment: ok if it is the issue then I try to increase the refreshing time and watch if it resolve? thanks again.

Comment: Sure. perhaps every 5 seconds is taxing on your server and it eventually catches up to it where it can't complete the request within 5 seconds. I suggest you open 20-40 windows of your views auto-refresh and see if it affects your performance. Views auto refresh should only be used if you are paying premium web hosting.

Comment: I increased the time and flush the views cache but after 1:30-2 hrs again the alert pop up. what to do.

Comment: what did you increase the time to? since the interval increased, and the time until failure increased, it still sounds like something building up in the system.  Are there any log errors when it happens?

Comment: well, if you just want to get ridoff the error popup, you could install the sandbox module.

Comment: @geoff I had increased the time of header global auto-refresh and I cant increase it up to 8 seconds as I need atleast 7-8 seconds to get latest record. any way thanks both. I will try that module but is that also resume my ajax again or it will stop when the time will come of pop up? thanks again.